# laravel multiple tables exploded data

Tags: php, database, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

I have this tables where I have inserted multiple imploded data which I can immediately pull from the database as it is just the ID of another table however I cannot show their names on the table
I have an Incident_Table and IncidentType_table I can already show the data but I'm still missing a few things to show the data on my tables instead of just showing 1,3 in my views it should be
1-Police
2-Fire Fighters
3-Ambulance
4-Others

[image]

regarding on my code this is what I have so far

```
 public function index()
{

    $Incidents = Incident::all(); // I get 1,3 as a collection

   // 1 - Police and 3 - Ambulance 
    foreach ($Incidents as $incident) {
        $request_responder = explode(",", $incident->response_needed_id);
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($request_responder); $i++) {
            $requested_responder[] = ResponderType::with('incident')->get()->where('id', '=', $request_responder[$i]);
        }
        $requested_responder = implode(',', $request_responder);
    }
 dd($requested_responder); //show only 1,3 should be Police, Ambulance
    return view('dispatch.index', compact('Incidents'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your blade template or model, it is difficult to see where the values "1-Police 2-Fire Fighters 3-Ambulance 4-Others" would come from. However, you can solve your current problem from within this current scope by using this.

```
public function index()
{
    $Incidents = Incident::all(); // I get 1,3 as a collection

    $incident_type = ['Police', 'Fire Fighters', 'Ambulance', 'Others']; // 1 - Police and 3 - Ambulance
    foreach ($Incidents as $incident) {
        $request_responder = explode(",", $incident->response_needed_id);
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($request_responder); $i++) {
            $requested_responder[] = ResponderType::with('incident')->get()->where('id', '=', $request_responder[$i]);
        }
        $requested_responder = implode(', ', $incident_type[$request_responder-1]); // We minus 1 because the array starts from 0
    }

    return view('dispatch.index', compact('Incidents', 'requested_responder'));
}
```

Comment: for clarification on where the incident_type data came from it's form another table for the dropdown list in which I selected 1 and 3 id values on the show page it doesn't show the name of the id the police and ambulance..

Comment: @Joshua can you please clarify by posting the model/controller or show blade template for this?